# Rails run rake:scheduler after start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to run a rake command after starting a rails server.

However, when I try to call `system(rake reque:scheduler")` in `config.before_initialise`,
the command appears to run in an infinate loop.

I've searched other sites for an answer, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to start that process inside Rails. Take a look at Foreman: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Comment: customer said he did not want to run everything by hand
want that all start when the server starts